# How can I write a dataframe to a local sqlite3 file?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv

I've got a directory of csv files which I would rather have as a `sqlite3` database.  What is the best way to write each csv file as a table in a database?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution

```
import pandas as pd #IO
import sqlite3 #To write database
import glob #loop through working directory

cxn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite3')

for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):

    table_name = file[:-4] #File name without .csv
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.to_sql(table_name, cxn, index = False)
```

Comment: In case others come here to find a solution, would you consider editing your answer to show your import of pandas?